# Ebean ORM not working with oracle cursor

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, ebean

I have  a procedure which return two variable. one of them is cursor.
I tried to do here so

```
String removalQuery = "{call REA.FILL_EVENT.REMOVAL_73_1_1(?,?,?,?) } ";
        CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(removalQuery);
        cs.setParameter(1,doc.poeSteamTurbine.vid);
        cs.setParameter(2,doc.form.periodId);
        cs.registerOut(3, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOut(4, Types.REF_CURSOR);
        Ebean.execute(cs);
```

But it causes an error

```
2012 is incorrect data type
```

Ebean able to work with cursors?

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question is old now, but I'll write this in case it helps someone.

I came up with a similar issue, connecting to an Oracle database. In my case the problem was the `REF_CURSOR` type, which produces the error you describe. My solution was to change it to `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR`, which solved the problem.

If you are not using an Oracle database the type is going to be something else, but you still need to change it.